# NetLocalGroupAddMembers returns success, but It is not working as expected

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I had a problem with `LookupAccountName`, [wrote a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085009/access-violation-writing-location-0x00000000-when-using-lookupaccountname/48085155#48085155) and figured it out I had to use `LookupAccountName` twice to work. Now I am trying to use `NetLocalGroupAddMembers` with the SID that I got from `LookupAccountName`, it returns success, but the newly created users won't be added to Users group.

I am getting the Users group from the `CreateWellKnownSid`, translating it to string using `LookupAccountSid` and sending the account SID to `NetLocalGroupAddMembers` by translating the first argument (the new account name) to SID with `LookupAccountName.`

**EDIT:**

This is a testable set of code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <LM.h>
#include <sddl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Netapi32.lib")
#define MAX_NAME 256

VOID ShowError(DWORD errorCode)
{
    //FormatMessageW
    DWORD flags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS;
    LPWSTR errorMessage;
    DWORD size = 0;

    if (!FormatMessageW(flags, NULL, errorCode, 0, (LPWSTR)&errorMessage, size, NULL))
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Could not get the format message, error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    wprintf(L"\n%s\n", errorMessage);

    LocalFree(errorMessage);
}


int wmain(int argc, WCHAR **argv)
{
    //NetUserAdd function
    NET_API_STATUS addUser;
    DWORD infoLevel = 1;        //USER_INFO_1
    USER_INFO_1 userData;
    DWORD paramError = 0;

    //LocalAlloc
    UINT memAttributes = LMEM_FIXED;
    DWORD sidSize = SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE;

    //CreateWellKnownSid
    WELL_KNOWN_SID_TYPE sidType = WinBuiltinUsersSid;
    PSID groupSID;

    //LookupAccountSid
    WCHAR name[MAX_NAME];
    DWORD nameSize = MAX_NAME;
    WCHAR domainName[MAX_NAME];
    DWORD domainNameSize = MAX_NAME;
    SID_NAME_USE accountType;

    //LookupAccountName
    LPCWSTR machine = NULL;
    BYTE accountSIDBuf[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE];
    PSID accountSID = (PSID)accountSIDBuf;
    DWORD cbSid = 0;
    SID_NAME_USE typeOfAccount;
    /*WCHAR refDomain[MAX_NAME];*/
    DWORD cchRefDomain = 0;

    //NetLocalGroupAddMembers
    NET_API_STATUS localGroupAdd;
    DWORD levelOfData = 0;  //LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_0
    LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_0 localMembers;
    DWORD totalEntries = 0;


    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"\nUsage: %s [UserName]\n", *argv);
        return 1;

    }

    //Set up USER_INFO_1 structure
    userData.usri1_name = argv[1];
    userData.usri1_password = NULL;
    userData.usri1_priv = USER_PRIV_USER;
    userData.usri1_home_dir = NULL;
    userData.usri1_comment = NULL;
    userData.usri1_flags = UF_SCRIPT;
    userData.usri1_script_path = NULL;

    addUser = NetUserAdd(NULL, infoLevel, (LPBYTE)&userData, &paramError);

    if (addUser != NERR_Success)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"\nA system error has ocurred: %d\n", addUser);

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        //Let's allocate memory for the SID
        if (!(groupSID = LocalAlloc(memAttributes, sidSize)))   //if fails
        {
            ShowError(GetLastError());
            exit(1);

        }

        //Let's create a SID for Users group
        if (!CreateWellKnownSid(sidType, NULL, groupSID, &sidSize))
        {
            ShowError(GetLastError());
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {

            if (!LookupAccountSidW(NULL, groupSID, name, &nameSize,
                domainName, &domainNameSize, &accountType))
            {
                ShowError(GetLastError());
                return 1;

            }

            if (!LookupAccountNameW(NULL, argv[1], NULL, &cbSid, NULL, &cchRefDomain, &typeOfAccount))
            {
                ShowError(GetLastError());
                /*exit(1);*/

            }

            PSID theSID;
            LPWSTR refDomainName = (LPWSTR)malloc(cchRefDomain * sizeof(WCHAR));

            if (!(theSID = LocalAlloc(memAttributes, cbSid)))
            {
                ShowError(GetLastError());
                exit(1);
            }

            if (refDomainName == NULL)
            {
                fwprintf(stderr, L"Error allocating memory for RefDomainName \n");
                exit(1);
            }

            //Here we go again! 
            if (!LookupAccountNameW(NULL, argv[1], theSID, &cbSid,
                refDomainName, &cchRefDomain, &typeOfAccount))
            {
                ShowError(GetLastError());
                exit(1);

            }

            //Here I should be able to use NetLocalGroupAddMembers
            //to add the user passed as argument to the Users group. 
            localMembers.lgrmi0_sid = theSID;

            localGroupAdd = NetLocalGroupAddMembers(NULL, name, levelOfData, (LPBYTE)&localMembers, totalEntries);

            if (localGroupAdd != NERR_Success)
            {
                ShowError(localGroupAdd);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {

                ShowError(localGroupAdd);

            }

            LocalFree(theSID);
            free(refDomainName);

        }

        LocalFree(groupSID);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result I got, as expected:

> The data area passed to a system call is too small.
>
> The operation completed successfully.

But when I query the newly created user with Net User, It says:

> Local Group Memberships
>
> Global Group Membership *None

It should say Users in the Local Group Membership.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Code is incomplete. We don't know, what `totalEntries` or `localMembers` are. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for answering. I am sorry, I have just added a testable set of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `NetLocalGroupAddMembers` with `totalentries`=0, but you should call it with 1.

Side notes:

Is there any good reason to put all variables at the top and not declare them where you need them? Locality might have helped you find the error.

`usri1_password` is not documented to be allowed to be `NULL`.

Are you sure you want to pass `NULL` everywhere as machine/system name. Sometimes this is something different than ".", see for example `LookupAccountSidW`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have no reasons to put all my variables on top, just have no idea where the best would be. It dit work with NULL for password, however I am going to set it, as well as a variable for machine name. Thanks again.

Comment: password NULL might be valid - at least it works. But I am surprised to see that it is not documented. Variables: declare them when needed, not before. That allows you to directly initialize them and make some of them const.